# Не сохраняется модель в базе: Exception (Database Exception) &#039;yii\db\Exception&#039

Tags: php, yii2

Добрый день, есть такой код в контроллере:

```
public function actionRegistration()
    {
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
        {
            $usersModel = new UsersModel();

            $usersModel -> setScenario('registration');
            $usersModel -> setAttributes($_POST['UsersModel'], true);

            if($usersModel -> validate() && $usersModel -> registration())
            {
                $usersModel -> id = $usersModel ->guid();
                $usersModel -> login = $usersModel->email;              
                $usersModel -> hash = md5(rand()) . '_' . md5(rand());              
                $usersModel -> save(false); 

                return json_encode([200, Yii::t('yii', 'In a letter sent to your e-mail to confirm your email address. mail, please read it')]);
            }
            else
            {
                return json_encode([500, Yii::t('yii', 'incorrectly entered e-mail')]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, Yii::t('yii', 'Page not found.'));
        }
    }
```

Вроде все просто, но при вызове `save()` выкидывает ошибку:

```
<pre>Exception (Database Exception) &#039;yii\db\Exception&#039; with message &#039;SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field &#039;login&#039; doesn&#039;t have a default value
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `users` (`id`) VALUES (NULL)&#039; 

in C:\sergey\sites\bitask.com\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:534
```

Полю id почему то присваивается NULL, в yii 1.1 все время просто вызывал save(), а тут парни что то перемудрили. При вызове var_dump($usersModel), показывает, что все поля корректно заполнены, особенно id никак разобраться не могу, заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, это все Yii1, я определял в модели все поля таблицы в виде публичных переменных а в Yii2 это как раз приводит к таким последствиям, все переменные переопределяются в пустые значения. Просто только изучаю. Отдельное спасибо за `Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash`

Answer (score 1):

Что касается NULL:

Вероятнее всего `guid()` возвращает значение, которое либо не проходит валидацию, либо иного типа, нежели определено в схеме таблицы users.

Что касается вашей ошибки - MySQL говорит, что поле login не может быть NULL.
Поскольку в коде я вижу установку логина в емейл, возможно вы пытаетесь сохранить запись в функции `registration()` и там это поле пустое.

PS: Вместо md5 лучше использовать `Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash`